# "at the latest" vs latest

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, word-difference

> He is not in bed but for his goodness he needs to go to bed latest at 10 o'clock.

Q: I think in this sentence, it is correct to use "at the latest" instead of "latest". What is your opinion?

Comment: Yes, a native English speaker would usually say, '... he needs to go to bed by 10 o'clock at the lastest'. The same speaker would probably say, '... for his health', or possibly, '... for his benefit', instead of, '... for his goodness'.

Answer (score 1):

The order should be "... by 10 o'clock at the latest"

As noted in comments, the word "goodness doesn't fit properly here. Perhaps "for his  sake" or "for his benefit"